# Ansible: Change value in template based on deployment

Tags: python, templates, ansible, jinja2

Is it possible for change value on a deployment basis with ansible? I'm configuring keepalived on two machines, I'd like to add a loop for the priority.

I can't loop or use the range() function as that'd just loop within the same deployment.

I'm trying to set priority:

- lb1 = 100
- lb2 = 101

My vrrp instance looks like this so far:

```
vrrp_instance VI_1 {
    state MASTER
    interface {{ int }}
    virtual_router_id 51
    priority 100 <------------------- I'd like to iterate this value
    advert_int 1
    authentication {
        auth_type PASS
        auth_pass 1111
    }
    virtual_ipaddress {
      # supports up to 20 by default
        {% for ip in vips %}
           {{ ip.addr }}
        {% endfor %}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use host index inside your template like this (if you don't care about who will get higher priority):

```
priority {{ play_hosts.index(inventory_hostname) }}
```

Or you can assign priorities in advance as host variables in your inventory file like this:

```
server1 vrrp_priority=100
server2 vrrp_priority=150
```

... and then use it inside your template:

```
priority {{ vrrp_priority }}
```

Comment: uuuuuugh host_vars I feel like such an idiot. Of course, that's pretty clean. Thanks